# 403 Forbidden response when calling the web service in secured 2 way ssl environment

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, ssl, jakarta-ee

I have a restful web service implemented using apache cfx. The URL of the web service is like htts://hostname:port/ServiceName/param1/param2/param3.

It is running in a tomcat hardening environment and in the web xml security constrains are configured as below.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Source Name</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServiceName</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ws-role-name</role-name>
        <role-name>ws-admin-role-name</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This was tested in same configuration environments with 2 way SSL enabled and I was able to call the web service using a curl command successfully. But in another environment with same tomcat hardening enabled and 2 way SSL support when calling the web service I received the following error.

```
    < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1027
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Sat, 10 Oct 2016 01:02:23 GMT
< Server: Jetty
< 
<html><head><title>Jetty - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Access to the requested resource has been denied</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Jetty</h3></body></ht* Connection #0 to host host name left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

But once the url-pattern is changed to,

```
<url-pattern>/ServiceName/*</url-pattern>
```

I was able to call the web service and receive the response as excepted. But in the other environments same as this this worked fine (tomcat hardening the 2 way ssl enabled).

Is there any configuration in tomcat hardening or 2 way SSL that could be a reason for the above mentioned issue?